# How can I run uWsgi as a service in CentOs?

Tags: python, uwsgi

I am in a hurry, I can find out how to do this but I need some help to achieve this without loosing too much time.
Currently what I do to run a uWsgi instance along with my ini file is just:

```
uwsgi --ini /home/myonlinesite/uwsgi.ini --pidfile /var/run/uwsgi_serv.pid
```

and then to stop:

```
uwsgi --stop  /var/run/uwsgi_serv.pid.
```

By the way, I have this code inside a uwsgi init file in my /etc/init.d/uwsgi.
so when I run /etc/init.d/uwsgi start it executes the ini config file and when I execute /etc/init.d/uwsgi stop it stops the uwsgi process id.

The problem is that when I start the uWsgi service it runs normally and logs every http request, any debug print and so on, but when I close putty which is where I run my Vps it kills all uWsgi process and quits the site from being displayed.

I do not know if I have to touch the pid file only, or what do I need to do leave the uWsgi process executing and I can close putty.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `nohup` to start the uWsgi process should solve your problem of the process stopping when you log out.

[A tutorial](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/nohup-execute-commands-after-you-exit-from-a-shell-prompt.html)

Comment: Also a terminal multiplexer like tmux or screen would do here.

Comment: A much better option is to either create a conf file in **/etc/init/app.conf** with **runlevels** and use it as **sudo initctl start | restart | stop app**  or create a service in **/etc/init.d/app** with **chkconfig runlevels** and all operations.

Answer (score 5):

If you are setting the parameters in the command line, add the flag `-d file.log` to your command (`-d` stands for daemonize):

```
uwsgi --ini /home/myonlinesite/uwsgi.ini --pidfile /var/run/uwsgi_serv.pid -d file.log
```

If you are setting the parameters in a config file, add the following line in your config:

```
daemonize = /absolute/path/to/file.log
```

In both cases, uWsgi will run in the background and log everything in file.log. Given these options, there is no need using nohup et al.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I've followed this solution and it works flawlessly

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to add

daemon = logfile

to your config